# Swift SearchBar and Tableview result issue

Tags: swift, tableview, searchbar

[image]

Hello

As seen on the image, when i search anything, it over-writes the results on original cells. White ones the results without any search, black ones are the results of a search. I have no issue or error on clickin cells and segues. What could cause this? Thank you !

PS: My tableview populates from 3 different MS SQL Query over internet, and they merge in a single array. So when i search it's not re-query on the MS SQL

Here is my code: "I removed some unnecessary parts like effects and such"

```
import UIKit

class KalipTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    var link = ""
    var profillistesi = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var filtered:[String] = []

    @IBAction func getir(sender: AnyObject) {

        if self.link == "checking external ip here" {

            var client = SQLClient()
            client.connect("server-ip", username: "username", password: "password", database: "database-name") {
                success in

                if success {
                    client.execute("select KalipNo from Kaliplar order by KalipNo asc") {
                        sonuc in

                        for table in sonuc as NSArray {
                            for row in table as! NSArray {
                                for column in row as! NSDictionary {
                                    self.profillistesi.append("\(column.value)")

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        client.disconnect()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if self.link == "checking emergency external ip here"

            var client = SQLClient()
            client.connect("server-ip", username: "username", password: "password", database: "database-name") {
                success in

                if success {
                    client.execute("select KalipNo from Kaliplar order by KalipNo asc") {
                        sonuc in

                        for table in sonuc as NSArray {
                            for row in table as! NSArray {
                                for column in row as! NSDictionary {
                                    self.profillistesi.append("\(column.value)")

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        client.disconnect()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

            var client = SQLClient()
            client.connect("server-ip", username: "username", password: "password", database: "database-name") {
                success in

                if success {
                    client.execute("select KalipNo from Kaliplar order by KalipNo asc") {
                        sonuc in

                        for table in sonuc as NSArray {
                            for row in table as! NSArray {
                                for column in row as! NSDictionary {
                                    self.profillistesi.append("\(column.value)")

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        client.disconnect()
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self

        let url = NSURL(string: "external ip of server"
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            self.link = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        }
        task.resume()

       }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
        return  profillistesi.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> KalipTableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KalipTableViewCell

        if(searchActive){
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]

        } else {

        cell.kalipCell.text = profillistesi[indexPath.row] as? String

        }
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "kalipSegue" {

            let gecis: KalipViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! KalipViewController
            let gecis2 = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

            gecis.kalipNo = profillistesi[gecis2!]

        }

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = profillistesi.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code? Are you using two table views? One for displaying original data and second one for displaying search results?

Comment: no i'm using single tableview

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: OK, it's my bad, i miss-typed my label on search active cause. Sorry to waste your time